# Encoding a multipart/mixed HTTP Response (for Android Profiles)

Tags: node.js, rest, http, nginx, http-headers

I am trying to build a server to serve static files which happen to be passpoint certificates. This server does not need any dynamic pages. It should just serve the same static replies over and over again.

I have said "XML profile" file, and I would like to serve it. However the headers and structure that I am required to serve it with are rather complex. This is no ordinary HTTP GET.
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-passpoint
says:

> The base64-encoded content must consist of MIME multipart content with
>   a Content-Type of multipart/mixed. The following parts make up the
>   individual parts of the multi-part content:

and

> The Profile section must be transferred as base64-encoded,
>   UTF-8-encoded XML text

When I try to fudge it, by removing the multipart/mixed bits, Android's CertInstaller refuses to open the xml file because of an invalid mime type.

I have done alot of web development before with all of the popular servers: Tomcat, NodeJS, NginX, Apache, golang(gorilla), Python WSGI, etc...
But I am not sure how to approach the problem. I could swat this fly with a bazooka: By starting a dynamic server and manually sewing together the response with the proper headers.
However: My gut feeling tells me that I should be able to solve this with a static web server such as NGINX or Apache (or the static serving capabilities of any of the dynamic application servers ).
Is there an elegant solution to this?
Also, I have not been able to find any reference implementations of such an android-profile-server. Just looking at some testable sample code might help me sort out this dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the android source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/hotspot2/ConfigParser.java

It turns out you need to doubly encode everything in base64.
I ended up writing a small python utility to serve this.

Note: You need to serve this with HTTPS in order for android to accept the profile. Also, you need to use chrome browser. Stock/Firefox do not work with this on my phone

```
@app.route('/profiles/<filename>')
def multipart(filename):
    if("/" in filename):
        raise "ilegal name: "+filename
    with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
        profileData = myfile.read()
        #print data
    b64Profile=b64encode(profileData).decode('ascii')
    with open("cert.crt", 'r') as myfile:
        caCertData = myfile.read()
        #print data
    b64CaCert=b64encode(caCertData).decode('ascii')
    withHeaders='''Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=f6d6201be73d4e46988f789237cffb00
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

--f6d6201be73d4e46988f789237cffb00
Content-Type: application/x-passpoint-profile
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

'''+ b64Profile+'''

--f6d6201be73d4e46988f789237cffb00
Content-Type: application/x-x509-ca-cert
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

'''+b64CaCert+'''
--f6d6201be73d4e46988f789237cffb00--'''
    b64withHeaders=b64encode(withHeaders).decode('ascii')

    resp = make_response(b64withHeaders) #here you could use make_response(render_template(...)) too
    resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-wifi-config'
    resp.headers['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = 'base64'
    #resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/mixed; boundary=f6d6201be73d4e46988f789237cffb00'
    return resp
```

Comment: I'm trying to serve a passpoint certificate and following the python utility you have above I am able to get my android to launch the installer ("Install Wifi credentials to connect to networks available via ...."). But when I press install, I get a "can't install Wi-fi credentials. Try downloading the file again" error message. I was wondering, for the xml profile that you use, is it a file that follows this structure https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/wifi/tests/assets/pps/PerProviderSubscription.xml ? an OMA-DM XML file?

Comment: that link looks about right (I didn't scrutinize it or anyhitng, but it looks ok at a glance)

Comment: @eshalev How do you create the certificate which is included in the passpoint profile? Does this certificate and the one on the Radius be created and signed for the same FQDN?